# How to add username in toolbar link?

Tags: buddypress

I installed a plugin and want to add the link of the plugin in the toolbar. But I have an issue with the url. The url shows fullname, but I need to show username. I tried replacing `fullname` in the code with `id` and `domain`. But it did not work.

```
<?php  

  function wsi_menu2(){
    global $bp, $wp_admin_bar;

    // Only show if viewing a user

        // Provides: <body text='black'>
$bodytag = str_replace("Admin", "", $bp->loggedin_user->fullname);

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'parent' => 'my-account',
        'id'     => 'FacebookInviteFriends',
        'title'  => 'Album',
        'href'   => 'http://mysite.com/members/'.$bodytag.'/album/',
         'onclick' => 'FacebookInviteFriends();'
    ) );
  }

  function wsi_menu3(){
    global $bp, $wp_admin_bar;

    // Only show if viewing a user

        // Provides: <body text='black'>
$bodytag = str_replace("Admin", "", $bp->loggedin_user->fullname);
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'parent' => 'my-account-friends',
        'id'     => 'my-account-friends-social-invites',
        'title'  => __( 'Send Social Invites', 'buddypress' ),
        'href'   => 'http://mysite.com/members/$bp->loggedin_user->fullname/album/',
         'onclick' => 'FacebookInviteFriends();'
    ) );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'parent' => 'my-account',
        'id'     => 'FacebookInviteFriends',
        'title'  => 'Album',
        'href'   => 'http://mysite.com/members/'.$bodytag.'/album/',
         'onclick' => 'FacebookInviteFriends();'
    ) );
  }
```

Any idea how to make this work for username?

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling in the username directly from WordPress. I don't think BP will do it for you by default.

```
global $bp, $wp_admin_bar, $current_user;

$bodytag = str_replace("Admin", "", $current_user->user_login;);
```